# FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/4k' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13) Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, android-permissions, permission-denied

I have added every thing required to download files to local storage still I'm getting this error

In Manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
       

  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

In pubspec.yaml

```
permission_handler: ^6.1.1
```

In Build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 30
minSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 30


 Future<bool> _requestPermission(Permission permission, Permission permission3,
      Permission permission4) async {
    print("xxxx IN ");

    if (await permission.isGranted) {
      print('xxxx ohhh');
      return true;
    } else {
      await permission.request();
      .then((value) => () {
            print("xxxx value" + value.toString());
            if (value == PermissionStatus.granted) {
              print("xxxx PERMISSION GRANTED ");
              return true;
            } else {
              print("xxxx PERMISSION DENIED ");
            }
          })
      .whenComplete(() => print('xxxx COMPLETED'))
      .onError((error, stackTrace) => () {
            print("xxxx onError " + error);
            print("xxxx onError " + stackTrace.toString());
          })
      .catchError((onError) => () {
            print('xxxx catchError ' + onError.toString());
          });
      print("xxxx OUT ");
      // var result2 = await permission3.request();
      // var result3 = await permission4.request();

    }
    return false;
  }
```

from this function see what's printed
not getting printed from then()...

[image]

Please Please help me out :)

Answer (score 3):

Use  `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the `application` tag not in `<activity>` tag:

```
<application         
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" >
```

Answer (score 1):

what is work for me this

```
permission_handler: ^8.3.0 // use this version
```

and in your code

```
 final status = await Permission.storage.request();

 var state = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.status;
 var state2 = await Permission.storage.status;


if (status.isGranted) {
  directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!;

}
if (!state2.isGranted) {
  await Permission.storage.request();
}
if (!state.isGranted) {
  await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
}
if (!await directory!.exists()) {
  await directory.create(recursive: true);
}
```

and in the my permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"> 
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses- 
permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION"/>
```